# Where is git object "master^{tree}" documented?

Tags: git

[**Section 10.4 Git Internals - Packfiles**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) of the Pro Git book has this command:

```bash
$ git cat-file -p master^{tree}
```

Where is the style of object specification `master^{tree}` documented? I know that `master^` is the previous `HEAD`, that is, the penultimate commit on the `master` branch, but what is the meaning of `{tree}` afterward, and where can I read about it?

Oddly enough, the following fails with `fatal: Not a valid object name master{tree}`:

```bash
$ git cat-file -p master{tree}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formats are explained in [git-revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) and seems it’s in this case a definition of what type of object to actually return:

> ^{}, e.g. v0.99.8^{commit} A suffix ^ followed by an object
> type name enclosed in brace pair means dereference the object at 
> recursively until an object of type  is found or the object
> cannot be dereferenced anymore (in which case, barf). For example, if
>  is a commit-ish, ^{commit} describes the corresponding
> commit object. Similarly, if  is a tree-ish, ^{tree}
> describes the corresponding tree object. ^0 is a short-hand for
> ^{commit}.